# How to show images downloaded in local storage in an Android Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-asynctask

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

    setContentView(R.layout.transparentpanel); 

    id_pubblicazione_md5 = getIntent();
    id_pubb_md5 = id_pubblicazione_md5.getStringExtra("id_md5");
    elenco_id_pagine = id_pubblicazione_md5.getIntegerArrayListExtra("elenco_id_pagine");

    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.sfogliabile);

    LoadingSfogliabile ldsf = new LoadingSfogliabile();
    ldsf.execute();
}

public class LoadingSfogliabile extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Bitmap, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap b) {
        System.out.println("onPostExecute");
        g.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                i.setImageBitmap(b);
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                return i;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        System.out.println(params.length);
        params = setSfogliabile();
        System.out.println(setSfogliabile().length);
        System.out.println(params.length);
        return params[0];
    }
}


public Bitmap[] setSfogliabile() {
    Bitmap[] pagine = new Bitmap[elenco_id_pagine.size()];

    /*************************************** FILE SYSTEM **************************************/
    dir_pag = new File(ConfigApp.absolutePathPubb+id_pubb_md5, "pagine");
    dir_pag.mkdirs();
    dir_thumb = new File(ConfigApp.absolutePathPubb+id_pubb_md5, "thumb");
    dir_thumb.mkdirs();

    for(int y = 0; y < elenco_id_pagine.size(); y++) {
        pagg = new File(dir_pag, Integer.toString(y+1));
        pagg.mkdirs();

        id_elemento = new File(pagg, (elenco_id_pagine.get(y)).toString());
        id_elemento.mkdirs();

        jpg_pagina = new File(id_elemento, ((elenco_id_pagine.get(y)).toString())+".jpg");

        try { 

    /************************** SALVATAGGIO DELLE IMMAGINI IN LOCALE **************************/
            String pagina = ConfigApp.urlPubbDir+id_pubb_md5+"/pagine/"+Integer.toString(y+1)+"/"+((elenco_id_pagine.get(y)).toString())+"/"+((elenco_id_pagine.get(y)).toString())+".jpg";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(jpg_pagina.getAbsolutePath());
            pagine[y] = imd.downloadBitmap(pagina);
            pagine[y].compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

    /******************************************************************************************/

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    /************************************* FINE FILE SYSTEM ***********************************/
    return pagine;
}`
```

> What's the matter?!?!?!

I don't understand what is the problem!!

Comment: Can you please tell us the problem you are seeing, and what you are expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two issues:

1) Your BaseAdapter subclass returns a count of 0 for its getCount method.  That means the GalleryView thinks there is nothing to display.

2) On a larger note, your anonymous BaseAdapter subclass doesn't have a data source.  The Gallery is intended to display a scrolling strip of items, so it expects your adapter to have a collection of items to display. You should consider doing one of the following:

- use an ArrayAdapter, passing an array
  of data items to the constructor.
- use
  a CursorAdapter, passing a cursor of
  data items to the constructor.
- If you
  choose to stick with the BaseAdapter,
  you should add some sort of data
  member to the class.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply, but the asynctask is correct?
doInBackground() method return a ArrayList of Bitmap, that's correct or it must return a Bitmap object? Thank you!!!

Comment: Not completely sure what your code is doing, but I would expect to see doInBackground() return an ArrayList of Bitmap.  Then you store the ArrayList in your Adapter.  The Adapter returns each item in the ArrayList via its getItem() method.  Keep in mind Android does have a fixed amount of storage for bitmaps, so you may want to limit the size of the ArrayList.